# Mysqld won't start after reboot

Tags: mysql

nothing in /var/log/mysql*.

syslog shows:

```
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 14:55:28 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld:
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: key_buffer_size=16777216
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: read_buffer_size=131072
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: max_used_connections=0
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: max_threads=800
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: thread_count=0
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: connection_count=0
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1765459 K  bytes of memory
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld:
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: Thread pointer: 0x0
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: terribly wrong...
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x7ff147039689]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x7ff146e4da53]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xeff0) [0x7ff14659fff0]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(page_cur_insert_rec_low+0x288) [0x7ff146f6c4b8]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(page_cur_parse_insert_rec+0x4fb) [0x7ff146f6d07b]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x58a6cd) [0x7ff146f576cd]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(recv_recover_page+0x4a7) [0x7ff146f5bfc7]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_page_io_complete+0x468) [0x7ff146f147d8]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(fil_aio_wait+0x122) [0x7ff146f2ed82]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5d2230) [0x7ff146f9f230]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x68ca) [0x7ff1465978ca]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7ff1450dfb6d]
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
Oct 25 09:55:28 mx mysqld: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Is in syslog. Everytime I try to restart mysqld I get FAILED.

Comment: Have you lost your databases?

Comment: Rebooting my system corrupted my databases. It was facilitated by the fact that everything was slowed down because I had non-optimal settings in my my.cnf. I had to back up my databases in /var/lib/mysql purge mysql from the system, reload it, and restore my databases. 40% of them were fine. The rest had to be restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the dump is the following:

> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html
>   contains information that should help you find out what is causing the
>   crash.

IMHO your best bet is to look at the info found in the above URL. It's verbose so I'm not going to cut and paste it here.

Regards,